# What is the best way to get all data from an HBase table for the last X hours?

Tags: hbase

I have stream of events which are written to HBase. Each event has `user_id`, `event_timestamp` and `description`.

Let's say I need to run an ETL job which retrieves all the data from a table for the last 12 hours. I thought about two ways to get the data (I'm using Java API):

1. To use `setTimeStamp` method of Scan.
2. To use `event_timestamp` as the rowkey prefix, but from my understanding it's bad practice because it leads to hotspots.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach:

> 1. To use `setTimeStamp` method of Scan.

sounds like a great idea. You're absolutely correct that the second approach:

> 2. To use `event_timestamp` as the rowkey prefix, but from my understanding it's bad practice because it leads to hotspots.

will generate hotspots, so it's not recommended to be used in HBase or Bigtable.

In general, creating a row key **prefix** monotonically increasing (such as time, year-month-day, etc.) or decreasing values (e.g., `INT_MAX` - current time, etc.) is highly problematic and thus not recommended.

You can certainly use time-derived values as a **suffix** for row keys: the reason you would do this is to avoid growing any single row to be too large, since rows are not split across regions, but kept as an atomic unit.

In that case, you will have time expressed in multiple ways:

1. once as a suffix of a row key, which will be coarse-grained, e.g., `<unique-id>-yyyymmdd`
2. the second time as the timestamp of the cell values themselves, which may be either:

   - *absolute time*, or
   - *relative* to the row's coarse-grained time suffix

Each of these approaches has their pros and cons, which depend on your query patterns and specific use case. If you want to query data in a particular time range globally, then using absolute time seems to be best, as then you can do a global scan with a time range, without creating complex row suffix filters, for example.